# Show or hide WooCommerce checkout fields based on pickup and delivery button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Dears,

i'm using snippet plugin to add my code to my ecommerace project , i have pickup and delivery plugin in my delivery option , what i'm trying to do is , once i select pickup option , customer address information fields will be hide which it is not logical to keep it appear and mandatory if pickup from restaurant selected.

i tried to add some other var and some of them works fine and other still appear after loading the page ( before loading and selecting the pickup they are disappear ( as an example the street ) and after loading street return and still appear

https://www.order.ramadaencorekuwait.com/checkout-2/

please let me know if there any issue with the code

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_js_script');
function custom_checkout_js_script() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = 'input[name="pi_delivery_type"]:checked',
            b = 'input[name="billing_address_4"]';
        var d = 'input[name="billing_address_3"]';
        var f = 'input[name="billing_avenue"]';
        var z = 'input[name="billing_address_2"]';
        var s = 'input[name="select2-billing_state-container"]';
        
        
        // Custom function that show hide specific field, based on radio input value
        function showHideField( value, field ){
            if ( value === 'pickup' ) {
                $(field).parent().parent().hide();
            } else {
                $(field).parent().parent().show();
            }
        }

        // On start after DOM is loaded
        showHideField( $(a).val(), b );
        showHideField( $(a).val(), d );
        showHideField( $(a).val(), f );
        showHideField( $(a).val(), z );
        showHideField( $(a).val(), s );
        // On radio button change live event
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on('change', a, function() {
            showHideField( $(this).val(), b );
            
            showHideField( $(this).val(), d );
            showHideField( $(this).val(), f );
            showHideField( $(this).val(), z );
            showHideField( $(this).val(), s );
        });
        
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to assign a class to b, d, f, z and s. If you've already defined 'a', then you could do something like:

```
$(a).change(function() {
   if ($(a).val() == 'pickup') {
      $(".special").hide();
   } else {
      $(".special").show();
   }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work with me , can you help me and reply with full code as per the one i share it before . Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that disables the submit form everywhere when the delivery method is local pickup.

You should replace (28): "local_pickup:28" with the id of your shipping method.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'disable_shipping_local_pickup' );
function disable_shipping_local_pickup( $available_gateways ) {
   // Part 1: Hide shipping based on the static choice @ Cart
   // Note: "#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields" (formerly "#customer_details .col-2", but was too broad & was also hidding additional fields that aren't shipping related that just happened to be in the second column) strictly depends on your theme
   $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
   $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
   if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup:28' ) ) {
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields').fadeOut();
      </script>
   <?php
   }
   // Part 2: Hide shipping based on the dynamic choice @ Checkout
   // Note: "#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields" (formerly "#customer_details .col-2", but was too broad & was also hidding additional fields that aren't shipping related that just happened to be in the second column) strictly depends on your theme
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('form.checkout').on('change','input[name^="shipping_method"]',function() {
            var val = jQuery('input[name^="shipping_method"]:checked').val(); // If it changed, then it must be the radio options so check the one that's selected
            if (val.match("^local_pickup:28")) {
              jQuery('#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields').fadeOut();
            } else {
              jQuery('#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields').fadeIn();
            }
         });
         // Also check if the zipcode switched to something where local pickup is the only option (similar to what's done in part 1 above, but happen based on what's currently being entered on the page [watch via ajaxComplete since the options that are available/selected might not be present when the zipcode change happens & it needs to load those in via AJAX])
         jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
             if(jQuery('input[name^="shipping_method"]').attr('type') === 'hidden'){ // There's only one option so check the hidden input field with the value
                var val = jQuery('input[name^="shipping_method"]').val();
            }else{ // Otherwise, it must be the radio options so check the one that's selected
                var val = jQuery('input[name^="shipping_method"]:checked').val();
            }
            if (val.match("^local_pickup:28")) {
              jQuery('#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields').fadeOut();
            } else {
              jQuery('#customer_details .woocommerce-shipping-fields').fadeIn();
            }
         });
      </script>
   <?php
}
```